# Why the <a> is changing the images Allignment

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at my website at following link and let me know why the  link tag change  alignment? before adding the link tag all image were aligned Horizontally and vertically but now the second image looks aligned lower!

[Here is the link](http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=248)

and here is the code:

```
enter code here
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- content -->
<div class="clearfix" id="items">
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=285">
<div class="boxlist">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-253" alt="imgPortf_1" src="http://ghazalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/imgWedd_1.jpg" />
<h2>Love</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=285">
<div class="boxlist">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-258" alt="imgPortf_2"    src="http://ghazalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/imgWedd_2.jpg" />
<h2>Beauty</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=186">
<div class="boxlist">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-259" alt="imgPortf_3"  src="http://ghazalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/imgWedd_4.jpg" />
<h2>Fun</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=290">
<div class="boxlist">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-259" alt="imgPortf_3" src="http://ghazalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/imgWedd_3.jpg" />
<h2>Favorite</h2>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<!-- End of content -->
</div>
<!-- End of wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the placement of the `p` tag.

```
<p><a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=276"></a><br>
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=292"></a></p>
```

If you remove this, the alignment is correct. You could move it to just after the wrapper div to solve the problem too...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p><a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=276"></a><br>
    <a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=292"></a></p>
    ...
```

**Update**

Technically, you do have `p` tags, because you have made a slight error in your HTML...

```
<a href="http://ghazalphoto.com/?page_id=276"></p>
```

On this line, you close a `p` tag, even though you have never opened one, so the browser is trying to guess what you meant.

If you inspect in Firebug (in Firefox) you'll see this wraps the link in a paragraph - so you can see the effect of the typo.

Comment: Thanks Steve but I do not have any <p> tag in my source code! so where it comes from?

Comment: You sort-of do - you have a closing tag even though you don't have an opening one (at least when I click "View Source" you do.)